# Does Cisco networking or cisco jobs has anything realated to linux/unix

Tags: linux, cisco

IN the path to cisco nteworking llike CCNA , CCNP , CCIE.

Does they are purely hardware based or somewhere unix/linux,window server knowledge has something to do with it.

I mean knowldege of linux system is required to become efficient CCNP OR CCIE or they are totally separate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessary to pass the certification. However, having some development experience can certainly make your working life easier, especially when it comes to repeating tasks (imagine checking if your 1500 switches have HTTP enabled or not, manually, compared to having some code doing it for you).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any unix/linux knowledge for CCNA and CCNP, may be a bit for some CCIE but I don't think.
Cisco certification are really only pure network and cisco oriented